# PHP variable is not usable - Script stops when trying to assign/use it

Tags: php, sql

I just came across a bug in my code that I wasn't able to fix for the last few hours. I am querying something from the database and then I am trying to use the results. However, whenever I try to access the content of the query result, the script just stops.

```
$recordcount = $db->query("SELECT optin_mail FROM games WHERE id = $game_id");
$result = $db->getrec();
echo "This will be executed without a problem";
if (isset ($result) && $result != null) echo $result;
echo "This won't be executed. The script stops in the line above";
```

I did a lot of testing and found out that everytime I try to assign $result, for example `$newVariable = $result;` or I try to access the content `$content = $result["name"];` it stops. Even echoing it or using `print_r($result);` will let the script crash instantly.

I really don't know what to do anymore. I checked the query and the result_count is 1. The function `getrec()` is basically just `mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryResult);` and works perfectly fine, I am using it multiple times in the same file.

Comment: what does it show you if you add `var_dump($result);` right after the first `echo` line?

Comment: wrap your code in try {} catch(\Exception $e) {echo $e->getMessage();} To see error.

Comment: Single `isset ($result)` is enough.

Comment: [Inspect](http://php.net/var_dump) the `$result` variable, double-check the documentation for `getrec()` and make sure you've configured PHP to display errors. I bet you're getting `Catchable fatal error: Object of class Whatever could not be converted to string`

Comment: Okay, using var_dump - the script crashes. No result. Using try and catch the script crashes too. The function getrec() looks like this: 
return mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->rs);
where "rs" is the result from the $db->query()

Comment: Try to change this second line `$result = $db->getrec();` to `$result = $db->getrec(); var_dump($result);` Does it show you anything? Does it still show you the output of the first `echo` on the 3rd line?

Comment: @AnnieTrubak No it doesn't show anything. Everything after and including var_dump($result) won't be executed. It just crashes everytime I use the variable

Comment: is your php error reporting turned on? any errors in the log? how do you know it crashes? Is it possible it's just taking very long time to execute?

Comment: Error Reporting is turned on, yes: error_reporting(E_ALL);
Just printing something out shouldn't take that long - I tried it anyways and waited about 60 seconds but nothing is happening

Comment: Did you check `mysqli_error()`?

Comment: Possible syntax error. Try changing `$recordcount = $db->query("SELECT optin_mail FROM games WHERE id = $game_id");` to `$recordcount = $db->query("SELECT optin_mail FROM games WHERE id = '" . $game_id . '");` and also try `$recordcount = $db->query("SELECT optin_mail FROM games WHERE id = 1");` and also try `$recordcount = $db->query("SELECT optin_mail FROM games WHERE id = '1' ");` if 1 is a valid id, otherwise use another number/string (you can also try `var_dump($game_id);` first and just replace the number `1` in my examples with that value. Anything works?

Comment: Okay, I finally found something out. It seems to be about the content of "optin_mail". The previous content was something like this: "Hey [first_name] <br> please click the following link [link] ..."
After changing the content to "hey" it works perfectly fine. I never thought this was a problem, because it worked before using this type of content. What can I do about that problem?

Comment: "Something like" is insufficient. Could you give an example of an exact string (full value of `optin_mail`) that fails?

Comment: @CM웃 Of course, the exakt string is: "Hallo [first_name] <br> Vielen Dank für die Teilnahme. Um Ihre Gewinnspielteilnahme zu bestätigen klicken sie bitten den folgenden Link an: <br> [link]"

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first of all, it's difficult to say what's wrong without seeing the insides of `getrec()` method. My guess is that you're trying to echo the wrong type of data. Function `mysqli_fetch_assoc` returns an array, thus echoing `$result` won't work.

Try

```
$recordCount = $db->query(sprintf('SELECT optin_main FROM games WHERE id = %s', $game_id));
$results = $db->getrec();
if ($results ?? null) {
    echo $results[0]['optin_main'];
}
```

Comment: But he also tried `print_r($result);` and that didn't work

Comment: Fair point, I'd try dump/var_dump it just to double check what's inside. Though it's difficult to tell where the problem lies just based on three lines of code as I mentioned in my answer. I believe, that based on information provided in the question, that is the best answer I could provide.